# How to create IProject without Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to mavenize a third part Eclipse's plugin,
but I need to create an instance of IProject to pass at `JavaCore.create(instance)` to obtain an instance of IJavaProject.

This application will not have workspace and will be better that depends from eclipse's libraries as less as I can.

So I can't use:

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject(...);
```

When I try to start my program I have this error report:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workspace is closed.
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace(ResourcesPlugin.java:367)
    at gr.uom.java.jdeodorant.helpers.JavaProjectHelper.createJavaProject(JavaProjectHelper.java:55)
    at gr.uom.java.jdeodorant.refactoring.actions.Index.initializeJavaProject(Index.java:28)
    at gr.uom.java.jdeodorant.refactoring.actions.Index.main(Index.java:53)
```

So is there any way to create this instance outside Eclipse, just passing the path of the project that I need?
Some ideas?

Comment: If you just need to build eclipse plugins or OSGi bundles with maven, have you considered Tycho - http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer: no.

The workspace requires the OSGi framework to start, and set the `osgi.instance.area` property.  It also needs some of the other *org.eclipse.core.runtime* services to be started.

JavaCore.create(*) is in JDT ... parts of *org.eclipse.jdt.core* might run without having the UI workbench up, but that really depend on which parts.

It might be possible to run a HEADLESS RCP application that includes the *org.eclipse.core.runtime* and *org.eclipse.core.resources* (workspace) without including any of the UI components, but you won't be able to use the workspace without starting up OSGi and the core runtime.

Comment: So there's no way to pass an external ".java" file as an IFile or ICompilationUnit without having eclipse workspace?

If the answer is yes, 
is there a way to simulate eclipse opening workspace? 
I tried to find something on the web but nothing helpful

Comment: no, in order to get an `IFile` the **.java** file has to be in an eclipse project in a workspace (and org.eclipse.core.resources must be started correctly).  In order to get an `ICompilationUnit`, you have to get an `IFile` and JDT core must be started correctly.

Comment: @Davide I am not sure what you call simulating opening a workspace. 
A workspace can be available in a java program without UI. You need: a) to start an OSGi container, b) to define a location where the JDT will store some metadata. No need to have the Eclipse UI to do this.
Have a look at my blog post where I explain this: https://jmini.github.io/blog/2020/2020-01-17_jdt-without-eclipse.html The setup is made in a regular maven project (with usage of bnd maven plugins for the OSGi part)