# how to pass external file to ASTParser or any compatible AST library?

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214202/how-to-create-iproject-without-eclipse/) previous question, I'm not able to get an IFile or ICompilationUnit outside eclipse.

I need *org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom* library to parse and extract tree structure.
I saw the method
*ASTParser parser = ....;

parser.**setSource(char[] source)**;*
how can I pass the path of a external project-file or directory?

I need bindings so this method must be set to true
*parser.setResolveBindings(**true**);*

If it wont be possible, do you know any compatible libraries to build an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree)?

Thanks

Comment: Is it fundamental to your needs that you have access to the AST using the eclipse AST parser, or will any parser that can parse and name-resolve work for you?  What do you intend to do with the AST and symbol tables?

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to use it as an Eclipse plugin or as a standalone Java application?

If it's as a Java application, I don't think you have any references to those IFile or ICompilationUnit, unless you use ASTParser.setEnvironment in order to create a new workspace (which I don't know how). If it's as a Java standalone application, check this examples:

http://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/tools/org.eclipse.objectteams/trunk/testplugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core.tests.compiler/src/org/eclipse/jdt/core/tests/dom/StandAloneASTParserTest.java

With that code you can convert any .java content into an AST and parse it (I never tried to insert new AST nodes and then write e new class with that, but I believe it's possible).

Here's my first try with that implementation: http://pasteit.com/19436

Answer (score 0):

You can read any file normally and convert it to char array; i don't see why would this be a problem. And from the jdt 3.6. version you can use setEnvironment so the setResolveBindings can actually work. More info: [link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/FAQ#Can_I_use_JDT_outside_Eclipse_to_manipulate_Java_code.3F).

People have used it, but to be honest, I am still not able to get bindings with this approach.